# Как сделать так, чтобы в vim команда f в Normal Mode распространялась на весь файл

Tags: vim

Насколько я знаю, команда f ищет символ по всему файлу справа. Однако у меня зона ее действия ограничивается концом строки. Как можно сделать так, чтобы она распространялась на весь файл?

Comment: `/a<Enter>` ищет `a` по всему файлу. `f` всегда был только для одной строки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Украду у @StanislavVolodarskiy*

/a ищет a по всему файлу. f всегда был только для одной строки.